# Could not download x86_64_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When I click 'run' on Android Studio, I got a wrong message.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not download x86_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408)
      > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/x86_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'http://117.128.6.36/cache/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/x86_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar?ich_args2=469-15172408060292_4a4fd95214f9e92d2a125477ffc75a18_10001002_9c896c2adec7f3d7913f518939a83798_8d1af01e118d680a7de369bbc67b99cf'.
            > Connect to 117.128.6.36:80 [/117.128.6.36] failed: Connection timed out: connect
   > Could not download x86_64_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408)
      > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'http://117.128.6.32/cache/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar?ich_args2=469-15172417060282_c6379c3b74cbe5c6510bd1dd15ff7877_10001002_9c896c2adec7f3d7913f518939a83798_1648250909497af7556e0012823cd639'.
            > Connect to 117.128.6.32:80 [/117.128.6.32] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The Android project build normally but Flutter got this messgae. Switch my network to mobile hotspot can't solve either. The url `http://117.128.6.36/cache/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/x86_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar?ich_args2=469-15172408060292_4a4fd95214f9e92d2a125477ffc75a18_10001002_9c896c2adec7f3d7913f518939a83798_8d1af01e118d680a7de369bbc67b99cf` can't be accessed but `http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar` can and download.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue and I resolved it by using VPN. [More info here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46878)